# How to implement decltype functionality - pre c++11, compile time

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time, decltype

I have a question if there is a way to implement decltype keyword functionality pre c++11.

I have a simplified class of vector

```
template <class T>
struct MyVector {

    typedef T ElementType;

    T* arrayPtr;
    uint64_t numberOfElements;
};
```

I want to be able to get the type T in a universal MACRO that will be usable with this MyVector

```
#define ALLOCATE_SPACE(VectorRef, numberOfItems) \
{ \
    arrayPtr = new decltype(VectorRef)::ElementType[numberOfItems]; \ \
} \
```

The problem is I can't use c++11 stuff. The perfect solution would be to make it 100% compile time type deduction.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Best Regards

Comment: Not when all you have at your disposal is standard C++ itself.

Comment: Besides, you don't need decltype. This is a job for a member function. Don't abuse macros

Comment: If there was a way to do this, C++ wouldn't need `decltype` and it wouldn't be added to the language.

Comment: StoryTeller : I need code to be 100% inlined this is the reason that I use macros. n.m. : I've seen implementation of static_asserts basing on templates using pre c++11 features so I thought something like this is also possible.

Comment: @MarcinK. What do you mean you need it to be 100% inlined? If you're worried about optimizations, don't. If you're worried about ODR, type `inline`

Comment: The instructions in macros need to be inlined in assembly code without CALL instruction. I need to achieve it because the program will be further analised for academic purposes

Comment: @MarcinK. could you please elaborate on the "academic purposes"

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. There is a boost macro accomplishing this magic:

```
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main() {
    int a; float b;
    BOOST_TYPEOF(a+b) c = a+b;
    std::cout << typeid(c).name() << std::endl;
}
```

prints `f` (float). [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/rrPjtP)

Though, as already pointed out in the comments, you don't need this for your problem. A simple template function would do the job.